# How to access the elements of a ControlTemplate in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I have a ControlTemplate defined in App.xaml. Now, I need to be able to handle certain UI events. In Visual Studio's XAML editor, if I attach a handler to an event, the handler is created in App.xaml.cs. However, I need to do this in pages that use this control template.

I'm thinking the only way is to iterate through the elements in the control template and find the right element and create handlers in pages. However, I'm not sure how to access the elements from the ControlTemplate object.

Does Xamarin provide a way to peek into the contents of a ControlTemplate?

Answer (score 8):

Although this is a old topic but the actual Xamarin Forms API provides the following and works out of the box:

```
contentView.GetTemplateChild("nameOfTheControl")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have **Page** instance you can cast it to **IPageController** and it's **InternalChildren** property contains controls from the template.

Here is an extension method I'm using to find controls by name

```cs
public static T FindTemplateElementByName<T> (this Page page, string name)
    where T: Element
{
    var pc = page as IPageController;
    if (pc == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    foreach (var child in pc.InternalChildren)
    {
        var result = child.FindByName<T> (name);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are the template elements read-only, or can you modify them, too?

Comment: Dude! You literally saved my life with this. Thank gawd!

Answer (score 1):

I havent found a way yet to iterate through the control template children.
I used template binding 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/template-binding/
to bind to a command object,  the properties for the commands are defined in my base page, then used a base view to define my commands and set them to the  binding backing properties in the basepage OnAppearing override.

I am working on a blog entry and will update this when I have code to show.

Comment: Great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you had the time for writing the blog entry so that you can post some code?