# Access custom control from ControlTemplate in current ContentPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to include a view with an `ActivityIndicator` on each page I use. Therefore I created a custom control together with an absolute/relative layout, which is necessary if you want to have it full screen. Other solutions embed the `ActivitIndicator` on each page. I'm searching for a solution which can do that "automatically".

Subclassing would be an option, but I want to have as much as possible in XAML, which my current solution can't provide (and the structure is obscure).

Now I found `ControlTemplate` and I put my custom view/control in there. But I saw that I can't access the custom control from `ContentPage`. There is [TemplateBinding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/template-binding/), where you can access public properties. E.g. you can change the text value of a label. But my case is a litte bit more complex and I need to access the control from the code behind file/model. Then I could call `show()` or `hide()`.

In [How to access the elements of a ControlTemplate in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690562/how-to-access-the-elements-of-a-controltemplate-in-xamarin-forms) someone proposes to use commanding, but that seems only available for a few controls (e.g. button) and not my custom control.

What can I do? Can I do something like `this.ControlTemplate.GetControl(controlName)`?

Comment: I think for _little bit more complex_ cases you could use custom controls, you could declare in custom control bindable properties, commands, events and manage what ever you want from page where you put your custom control.

Comment: That sounds good, but how can I access the custom control? It is only defined in the `ControlTemplate` and there is no reference to it on the page.

Comment: Rephrase: _you could use custom control_ **instead** of `ControlTemplate`. _how can I access the custom control?_ - by name `x:Name=""`

Comment: I edited my question to provide some more details. I also want to include some layout stuff, so I think a custom control can't do that.

Comment: Do you want to have `ActivityIndicator` on each page, but not declare it on each page?

Comment: Roughly speaking, yes. It is a custom control with `ActivityIndicator` and should be on many pages, but not all.

Comment: So, it's acceptable for you to add your custom control to each page that you need manually?

Comment: That is what I want to try now. I think there is no other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Back to my suggestion with custom control:

```
public partial class CustomActivityIndicator : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsBusyProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsBusy),
                                typeof(bool),
                                typeof(CustomActivityIndicator),
                                default(bool));

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsBusyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsBusyProperty, value); }
    }

    public CustomActivityIndicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="control"
      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.CustomActivityIndicator">
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy, Source={x:Reference control}}"/>
</Grid>
```

How to use:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SuperForms.Samples;assembly=SuperForms.Samples"
             x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.PageWithCustomActivityIndicator">
    <local:CustomActivityIndicator IsBusy="true"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know why...

If for example your custom control is

```
public class LibraryGridView : View
{
    public LibraryGridView()
    {

    }
}
```

Then you must use:

```
LibraryGridView hebrewFlowLayout = (LibraryGridView)XFVisualTreeHelper.FindTemplateElementByName<View>(this, "MyLayoutElement");
```

Notice the casting `LibraryGridView` and the `<View>`.